# How to fix Type 'AsymmetricMatcher<any>' is not assignable to type '() => void'. in jasmine/jest

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a object config where I send a function callback to a function.

```
test('should create a ComponentMockwith the needed config', () => {
        const config: MyConfig = {
           // more options
          myCallback: jasmine.anything()
        };

        sut.doYourThing(config);

        expect(ComponentMock.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(config);
      });
```

The problem I have is that after an update to the latest jest/jasmine I get this error in `myCallback: jasmine.anything()`:

> How to fix Type 'AsymmetricMatcher' is not assignable to type '() => void'. in jasmine/jest

If I ignore that line with `@ts-ignore` my test keeps working but I want to know why is the linter saying that and how to fix it since I really do not understand it.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue in my app, I have solved it by mapping troublesome type to any `jasmine.anything() as any`. Maybe it will solve your problem as well.

```js
test('should create a ComponentMockwith the needed config', () => {
        const config: EqListeningPlayerConfig = {
           // more options
          myCallback: jasmine.anything() as any // < --- here is what solved my issue
        };

        sut.doYourThing(config);

        expect(ComponentMock.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(config);
      });
```